# Move posts from game development to blender?

Tags: discussion

Some old posts before the blender SE like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/how-can-i-see-the-height-of-an-object-within-blender?rq=1 don't really belong in the game dev SE. Is there a procedure for moving them, or marking them as duplicates?

Comment: I was a bit surprised to see you do not have an account on game dev. What prompted this question?

Comment: Lol, I can see why you are confused, @david I googled a blender problem and was surprised when it came up on game dev

Answer (score 2):

In short you can't, they are stuck on game dev.

Any question older then 60 days can not be migrated. (Just a hard limit SE has coded into their system.)

Now for questions newer then 60 days. *Most* of the time site's migration paths will not be set up, so you can not simply vote to close because it should be on another site, and choose the correct site. (Mods can do that.)

Instead, you can flag for moderator attention with a custom message. Say why the question is off topic, and what site you are asking it be moved to (put the whole `http://blender.stackexchange.com` so it gets automatically turned in to a link).
I've flagged on a few blender questions on SO exactly like that.

This is the message I used on one of my flags.

> This question has nothing to do with programing, and should be moved to [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)